# angular material two check boxes, only one can be checked at a time

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, checkbox, angular-material

I am very new to Angular-material so this question might sound a bit silly, but please bear with me.

I have two checkboxes as following.

```
<mat-checkbox>Apply for Job</mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox>Modify a Job</mat-checkbox>
```

Let's say a user checked the first checkbox ("Apply for a Job") then later on clicks on "Modify Job" checkbox, I want the application to automatically uncheck the first one. How can I achieve this without using radio-buttons?

Comment: Why do you not want radio buttons, the html element specifically designed for this situation?

Comment: Because there are 5 checkboxes altogether (including the ones specified above), but it's just those two checkboxes that cannot be checked together. All other combinations of checkboxes checked are allowed.

Comment: So only those two would share a common name.

Comment: So.. are you suggesting to assign a common name for those two checkboxes and then use JQuery to accomplish?

Comment: Radio buttons that have the same name, with core html alone, will exclude each other from being selected.  There is no need for javascript to achieve that behavior with radio buttons.

Comment: Do you need to support having neither of those two options selected or does it always have to be one or the other?

Comment: @G.Tranter need to support having neither of those two options selected

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can put a condition on checked attribute, as in this example:

**Typescript**:

```
selected=-1;
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3];  let i = index">
  <mat-checkbox [checked]="selected === i" (change)="selected = i">Check me!</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t1a5dx)